# Get mouse coordinates with decimal precision

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I am looking for a way to get the mouse position in JS with some amount of decimal precision. I am trying to make an SVG drawing app and I don't like how the paint brush snaps to the nearest pixel instead of being interpolated between two. It seems that clientX is always an integer, even when zoomed in when there should be more precision. How do I get a more precise mouse position in JS?

Answer (score 1):

If you want decimal precision, you can use the pageX and pageY js properties. They give relative position to the entire document and are more precise than the ClientX and ClientY js properties. You can do so :

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  const svgRect = document.querySelector('svg').getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.pageX - svgRect.left;
  const y = event.pageY - svgRect.top;
  console.log(`Mouse position: (${x.toFixed(2)}, ${y.toFixed(2)})`);
});
```